# Mac: Terminal wont let me write/edit a file

Tags: macos, terminal, edit

I am trying to follow a tutorial on how to create an APP with Ruby on Rails but I am not able to edit a file from terminal!

When I am navigating on a file on terminal the cursor does not even blink. Like if I was on view only mode.

Can anyone help please! Thanks!

Comment: The terminal just shows the output of files - what application/command are you using to edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cursor in Apple's Terminal.app does not blink by default. This can be configured in the preferences (under the "Text" tab of a profile, near the bottom of the window), and is a purely cosmetic setting. It has no effect whatsoever on whether a file being displayed is editable.

Comment: Thanks! At the end the issue was that I did not know how to move around terminal. I first took a tutorial to learn the basics of mac terminal and second use "Sublime Text 2" to manage files.